# how to add array or row to array while foreach looping laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5, recursion

I need to get all products for category and sub categories when click on parent category

so i make loop or recursive loop to get all id for category and subcategory to search for its products

```
public function tree($category, $cats = array())
{
    $items = category_model::select('id')->where('parent_id', $category)->get();
    foreach ($items as $key=>$value)
    {
        //$cats = $value;
        $cats = Arr::add($cats, 'id', $value);
        self::tree($value, $cats);
    }
    return $cats;
}

public function allproduct(Request $request)
{
    return self::tree($request->id);
}
```

I have tried this code but looping with our result

I need to add this all id to make search for products through this array

Comment: A lot of typos!

Comment: You got some issues with `>`  :)

Comment: that is because of add question wrong only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your own code and make it work by taking all the category ids at once, instead of making a for each loop there.

Also, you are missing a terminating condition which is a must when using recursive functions.

Also, you don't need to process the same ids again and again if they have already been processed.

Taking all those points in mind, do something like this:

```
public function tree($cats, $alreadyProcessedCats = [])
{
    if (empty($cats)) {
        return [];
    }
    $newCatIds = [];
    foreach ($cats as $catId) {
        //do not process it if it was alreadt processed
        if (in_array($catId, $alreadyProcessedCats)) {
            continue;
        }
        //fetch all the categories id where parent id is one of the id which is present in the $cats
        $items = category_model::where('parent_id', $category)->pluck('id');
        if (empty($items)) {
            continue;
        }
        $items = $items->toArray();
        $newCatIds = array_merge($newCatIds, $items);
    }
    //terminal condition
    if (empty($newCatIds)) {
        return $cats;
    }
    $newCats = array_merge($cats, $newCatIds);
    return self::tree($newCats, $cats);
}

public function allproduct(Request $request)
{
    $allCategoriesIds = [$request->id];
    $allCategoriesIds = self::tree($allCategoriesIds);
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031  (SQL: select `id` from `category` where `parent_id` = ?)

at this line --------> 
$items = category_model::where('parent_id', $newCatIds)->pluck('id');

Answer (score 0):

Fix your foreach loop.

```
foreach ($items as $key=$value)
```

should be

```
foreach ($items as $key => $value)
```

I can't comment on that static Arr function (a Laravel thing I guess? due to the misuse of statics everywhere?)

Comment: There are a lot more typos in his code :) and i dont think fixing those typos is what OP wants